# nuxtjs Fontawesome some icons not able to display

Tags: javascript, vue.js, font-awesome, nuxtjs

Hi I have like to use some fontawesome icons such as Twitter icon.

In my nuxt.config.js, I have those lines below:

```
fontawesome: {
component: "fa",
icons: {
  solid: true,
  brands: true
 }
},
```

In html, I have these lines below:

```
  <fa icon="envelope"></fa>
  <fa icon="twitter"></fa>
```

However, the envelop is able to display but not the Twitter icon.  Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to specify the icons in html should be:

```
  <fa :icon="['fas', 'envelope']" />
  <fa :icon="['fas', 'lock']" />
  <fa :icon="['fas', 'sign-in-alt']" />
  <fa :icon="['fab', 'google']" />
  <fa :icon="['fab', 'linkedin']" />
  <fa :icon="['fab', 'twitch']" />
```

Comment: I did this from the beginning but some icons will display and some won't, checking into generated content after npm run generate I find some have been turned to svg and some not. Who could know what would be causing this behavior?